# check location permission is enable or not in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using below code to check the status of location permission when user navigate back from setting screen to check the location permission is enable or now.

```
checkPermission() async {
    bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (isLocationEnabled) {
      print("enable");
    } else {
      print("not enable");
    }
  }
```

navigate user to setting screen by this code :                             `PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();`

But the problem is locationserviceenable is always says true whether the location permission is disable or enable by user.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this method (you can see the doc [here](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-)):

```
bool isLocationEnabled = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
```

the flutter document says:

> serviceEnabled():
>   Return a boolean to know if the Location Service is enabled or if the user manually deactivated it.

for more information you can take a look at [this example](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).

Comment: this does not work. I had disable the permission but still it return true for isLocationEnabled.